# What the element next to it?

Tags: c

I wrote the following function to delete duplicated element in array and it work fine

```c
void deleteElement(int arr[], int size) {
    printf("\nArray after delete duplicate element :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size;) { // j not increase
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                for (int k = j; k < size; k++) {
                    arr[k] = arr[k + 1]; // set value of element k to value of the element next to it 
                }
                size--; // size -1 after delete   
            } 
            else {
                j++; // if no element deleted then loop again with j+1
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

i just confuse if the arr[k] reach end of array then what is value of arr[k+1] before it set to arr[k] ?

Comment: It doesn't point anywhere because it isn't a pointer. If you don't set it to a different value then it's still the same value as it was before. I think you may be thinking that you are somehow "deleting" entries in the array and making it smaller. That's not the case. The size of arrays in C cannot be changed after they have been defined.

Comment: my bad , my question actually is what the value of arr[k+1] before it set to arr[k] because if k reach end of array the k+1 is out of bound , it confuse me

Comment: if k reaches to the end of the array and you try to get `arr[k+1]` then it will most probably throw an error something like core dumped. However, it is undefined behaviour essentially.

Comment: That's the wrong question to ask really. The code should be written to never go beyond the bounds of the array. Accessing out of bounds memory is Undefined Behaviour which means the result is not predictable - it could read a random garbage value, it could crash, it could do any other behaviour.

Comment: @muyustan: Reading `arr[k+1]` will not “most probably throw an error.” Most C implementations do not do run-time bounds checks, and most hardware maps memory in units of pages such as 4096 bytes, so it is unlikely the end of a particular array would happen to be just at the end of a page boundary. If the compiler does not “notice” the array overrun during compilation, the most likely result is reading the next location in memory. If it does, then optimization can produce more troublesome results, but “throw an error” is still not the most probable (direct) result.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, it was probably way too brave to use the words "most probably". It is just I run into a core dumped generally in such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `k` loop is running one more iteration than it should.  The first time it's run, it is indexing past the array bounds.  It is not *writing* past the array bounds, but it is *reading* past the array bounds.  It's copying one element too many.

The problem is easily fixed by adjusting the array size *before* entering the loop, rather than after.  I.e.

```
    size--;
    for (int k = j; k < size; k++) {
        arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
    }
```

You only care about the values that are less than the *new* `size`, so you can stop copying after that.

Note that if the last element is the duplicate, the loop won't do anything at all, because it doesn't have to.  All that's needed is the size adjustment in that case.

You'll probably want to return the new `size` back to the caller when done.